# Don't allow pulling of specific remote while on specific local branch

Tags: git

In git, I have a branch called `localbranch1` and i do a `git pull origin remotebranch1`

I have another local branch called `localbranch2` which should be pulling from `remotebranch2`

I have a habbit of doing a `git pull origin remotebranch1` accidently when I'm on `localbranch2` which cause merges that I don't want to make happen.

Is there a way to "lock" or restrict myself from pulling from a different branch? It would be great if I got some type of error or warning when trying to pull from a different remote branch. Or should I approaching this workflow in a completely different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of the mentioned local branches always corresponds to the same branch on `origin`, the easiest solution is to set up the branches to track the remote branch, and then simply use `git pull origin`:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream localbranch1 origin/remotebranch1
Branch localbranch1 set up to track remote branch remotebranch1 from origin.
  ...
$ git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to restrict this short of wrapping it in an "Are you sure you want to..." confirmation script. What would probably be best would be to make sure things are set up so that, no matter which branch you're on, a bare `git pull` does what you want it to, then break yourself of the habit of typing any more than `git pull` (or `git pull origin` if you have multiple remotes). Reserve `git pull <remote> <branch>` for unusual non-standard workflow events.